# Curl request is refusing connection to server using POST method

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am sending a post request to a url with following parameters:

```
{"invoice":"INV-521240","status":1,"method":"wallet","re":"testing_ref"}
```

I am testing same request with postman and it works. The problem is that the request isn't working from curl request I am sending:

Here is the code I am using:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_PORT => "7080",
CURLOPT_URL => "http://47.91.109.79:7080/moolapay/status",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"invoice\":\"INV-521240\",\"status\":1,\"method\":\"wallet\",\"re\":\"testing_ref\"}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/json",
"postman-token: b7732a5b-2d0d-1f9f-7557-b14a696385e9"
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
 echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but "isn't working" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "isn't working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc.

Comment: P.S. As a general point, it's not a good idea to build your JSON by hand like that. Instead create a PHP object and then use json_encode(). Then you won't create any syntax or encoding problems by accident.

Comment: _"with postman and it works"_ ...did you use PostMan to generate this cURL code for you?

Comment: @ADyson yes I used same code as postman. https://prnt.sc/xd4jz2

Comment: Ok. Well please do as I suggested and provide some actual debugging information that we could work with.